# How to configurate CLion to work with makefile instead of CMake.txt?

Tags: c, makefile, clion

I downloaded `CLion` IDE for C language development. When I create a new C project as a default IDE creates `CMake.txt` file, but I have a requirement (in university) work with `makefile`.

So, question is - how to change the configuration from `CMake.txt` to `makefile`?

Because here in configuration block I see `CMake project`, but don't see `makefile project`

[image]

CMake structure

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test_c C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)

add_executable(test_c main.c)
```

makefile structure

```
myprog1 : main.o
    gcc -g main.o -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o myprog1
main.o : main.c info.h
    gcc -c main.c -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o main.o
```

Comment: If you create a new Project a cmakelists.txt is created. And if  you build that project with Clion a makefile is created. So that’s basically the same thing.

Comment: @HWilmer edited my quesiton

Comment: CMake can generate Makefiles, but they will generally be ugly. If your university requires Makefiles, make sure you are allowed to use makefiles generated from another build system instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLion uses `CMakeLists.txt` to build your code. But the `CMakeList` generates a `Makefile`. So you don't have to configure CLion to work with a Makefile since it's auto generated at compilation by the CMakeLists. I recommend you to keep the `CMakeLists` because CLion uses it as configuration.

But if you want to use your own Makefile, you can create one as you usually do, and create a new build configuration. I suggest you to read this peace of documentation from CLion: [Managing Makefile Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/managing-makefile-projects.html#)

Comment: Yes, your answer was helpful, but eventually, I decided to go with my own workaround, I am working with `CMake` configuration as it was, but in parallel, I created a makefile and just checking that after every batch of editing all working with makefile configuration.